# bash: check if a variable's value is the name of an existing variable

Tags: bash

I will be reading variables in from a config file.  Say, for instance, that the file looks like this:

```
cfg1=hello
cfg2=there
```

My script will read that in, so it will have variables names `$cfg1` and `$cfg2`.  I now want to determine if the command line argument matches one of the defined variables.  I.e., if I execute `script.sh cfg1` I want my `if` statement to pass, but if I execute `script.sh cfg3` it should fail.

I'm aware of the `\$$varname` syntax, but frankly I can't figure out how it works. I've tried:

```
if [[ \$$1 ]]
```

but that's always passes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-v` test in `bash` 4.2 or later:

```
if [[ -v $1 ]]; then
    echo "Variable $1 is defined"
else
    echo "Variable $1 is not defined"
fi
```

[@choroba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38271942/1126841) should work in any earlier version one is likely to be using.

Comment: Good to know about `-v`. Just to avoid potential confusion: `-v $1` works perfectly here, because the _value_ of `$1` is the _name_ of the variable whose existence to test.
By contrast, you can use neither  `-v $1`  nor `-v 1` to test if `$1` _itself_ was passed or not (examine `$#` for that).

Answer (score 5):

You can use parameter expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash

cfg1=hello
cfg2=''

for varname in cfg{1..3} ; do
    echo $varname
    if [[ ${!varname+1} ]] ; then
        echo ok
    fi
done
```

- `+1` replaces the value with `1` if the variable is defined.
- `!` introduces variable indirection, i.e. the variable `$varname` is used as the variable's name.